# JSF 1.2 Custom Component - Body Content From Backing Bean

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, custom-component

I am developing a custom component using JSF 1.2. My tag class extends `UIComponentELTag` and has variables of type `ValueExpression`. The values for these are getting set from the corresponding attributes of the tag (using `setProperties` function), for example

```
<sr:show name="#{backingBean.name}" ...> #{backingBean.mainContent}</sr:show>
```

I am stuck when I try to get the bodyContent of the tag as a binding value.
This is how far I have proceeded:

```
public int doAfterBody() throws JspException{
    if(bodyContent!=null) {
        String body = bodyContent.getString();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIComponent component = super.findComponent(context);
        MyComp myComp= (MyComp) component;
        myComp.setMain(body);
    }
    bodyContent.clearBody();
    return SKIP_BODY;
}
```

If the body of the tag does not contain binding value, this code works fine. I want to check if the body has binding value and then set the value from the bean.

In JSF 1.1, I checked this using `isValueReference(body)`. How do I achieve this in JSF 1.2? I could not find any examples of getting the body content as binding value anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply add another variable e.g. "contents" and bind that to the body text you want to render?

```
<sr:show name="#{backingBean.name}" text="#{backingBean.mainContent}" />
```

Or simply:

```
<sr:show bean="#{backingBean} />
```

and render the whole lot.

Comment: If the user wants to provide the value directly without a bean, is it advisable to put a whole lot of content as part of tag attribute?(like, text=mainContent, where mainContent may contain huge content or xml or anything else)The custom tag should support both binding value as well as direct value.

Comment: I'm just learning this stuff myself - sorry. Depending on how much logic you have vs formatting, you could just use facelets composition components for this. Also, you can separate presentation logic into one tag and have it set a variable with the result, then use other elements for formatting

Comment: I allow the main content to be entered in the body of the tag. And I also provide an attribute text which can take a ValueExpression. This way the user can enter formatted hardcoded text in body of the tag or he can provide the value of text attribute from backing bean. I settled down with this solution. Hope others find this information useful.